# wp_create_nonce function doesn't work inside a plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, forms, security, nonce

I am writing a WordPress plugin which is creating a form in one of its functions. It looks like this (very simplyfied):

```
class MyPlugin {
   public function createForm() {
      $nonce = wp_create_nonce('my_form_nonce');
      echo '&lt;input type="hidden" value=" . $nonce . "&gt;';
   }
}
```

This is not working. I get PHP error message function `wp_create_nonce` doesn't exist.

Well I understand that there are not all WP functions available in my custom plugin class context. But how do I do this? How do I implement WP token security inside my plugin form? What is the common approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wp_create_nonce`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_nonce/) is a [pluggable function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions) loaded after plugins are loaded.

Be sure to call your class method on proper hook, [`'init'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) (or later) is a good place: once your function output something (a form) there is no reason to run earlier than that.

Comment: Thank you for explaining how things inside Wordpress works. But the problem is, my plugin outputs the HTML form via shortcode function and in that moment wp_create_nonce in not available but needed for the creation of the form. I am stuck here :-)

Comment: @Macejkou a shortcode function should run when post content is shown on page, and there `wp_create_nonce` should be available. If isn't available means you are running the shortcode too early, impossible to say what you are doing wrong without seeing the code.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a quick reaction. You were right! I was calling the shortcode callback in plugins constructor. It was indeed to early. Wrapped it in init callbaback and works like charm.